# Graphql-java: How can I get DataFetchingEnvironment?

Tags: graphql-java

I can get it from the method "get(DataFetchingEnvironment environment)" in DataFetcher.

But I want to get it from other ways.

Answer (score 0):

Very confusing question. The `DataFetchingEnvironment` is only available to `DataFetcher`s, as it contains the info needed to resolve the value of one specific field (e.g. the parent field, the source value etc). It makes no sense to get it from elsewhere because to which field would it be related then?

Are you maybe looking to get access to [`ExecutionContext`](https://github.com/graphql-java/graphql-java/blob/master/src/main/java/graphql/execution/ExecutionContext.java)? That's the info shared between the `DataFetcher`s, as it's not tied to a specific field, and makes a lot more sense to get from outside. If that's the case, you can obtain it from an `ExecutionStrategy` at various stages (you can provide a custom `ExecutionStrategy`) or from an [`Instrumentation`](https://github.com/graphql-java/graphql-java/blob/master/src/main/java/graphql/execution/instrumentation/Instrumentation.java) at appropriate stages.